# Get all descendants of specific type SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Say I have an XML in which the information I'm trying to extract is at different levels of the hierarchy:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <info/>
    </person>
    <person>
        <info/>
    </person>
    <info/>
</people>
```

I want to get every info bit at all levels in the people tree, where I don't know how deep a certain branch might go.

Is there any way to get every descendant of a certain type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out xpath queries; you should be able to accomplish this by using something like `people//person`.  Here's a rough example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("people.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

// Look for all person elements that are decendents of people
$elements = $xpath->query("people//person");
```

List of possible queries: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: so is your example different than SimpleXML?

Comment: Yes, it is; though I think you can use XPath queries with SimpleXML as well.    http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php